# Change height of iPad PopOvercontroller

Tags: ipad, uipopovercontroller

I came up with a problem that i crated a PopViewController with tableview cells,But the height is too large,i want to display only 5 strings in the table cells,so my requirement is how to reduce the  height of the PopViewController.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the controller of the table view, add the following line in viewWillAppear:

```
self.contentSizeForViewInPopover = CGSizeMake(320.0, 400.0);
```

Comment: I checked ,but i wont reduce the height or size.

Comment: It does, assuming it's set in the view controller (table view) displayed in the popup. From the Apple docs for `contentSizeForViewInPopover` property: "This property contains the desired size for the view controller when it is displayed in a popover. By default, the width is set to 320 points and the height is set to 1100 points. You can change these values as needed."

Comment: ohh god,i cant get it.i set the above code to my viewwillappear method.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting [popoverContentSize](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIPopoverController_class/Reference/Reference.html)